# PyGame - Unattaching the FPS out of the program

Tags: python, pygame, frame-rate

I want to create something similar but with out the attachment of the fps in
    `clock.tick(30)`
here is the rest of the program

```
import pygame
st_X=180
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
st_Y=340
st_X_Change=0
pygame.init()
gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("space_invaders")
gameExit=False
pygame.display.update()
while(gameExit==False):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)    
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:

            gameExit=True
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                st_X_Change=-10
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                st_X_Change=10
    st_X+=st_X_Change
    gameDisplay.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,(255,255,255),[st_X,st_Y,40,10])
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: What's wrong with `Clock.tick`?

Comment: Is just that I what to make the same thing with out calling a frame rate

Comment: Why? You can use `time.clock`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach would be:
- store the starttime of the last update
- at the end of the update, get the current time
- get the difference between the two times
- subtract that difference from the desired time per frame (1/FPS-dx)
- let your program wait for that time (something like sleep() )

That will make your program run at your target FPS. There are other ways, but thats a nice and easy one.